# Look rotation viewing vector is zero in Unity when making UI

Tags: unity, gui, editors, exceptions

How can I tackle the problem: `Look rotation viewing vector is zero`?

Here is how I get it:

1. I add an Image from UI.
2. When the Image is added I click on it in the Hierarchy view.
3. When focus is on an Image I take the Canvas border and move it left.
4. I get the Exception.

Here are some screenshots of the process which takes place:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the last screenshot I selected the Canvas and tried to focus on it by pressing <kbd>F</kbd> in the Scene view. As you can see I am not able to resize the canvas anymore. That means that I would have to create a new Canvas and copy everything into it, which is pretty tiresome and error prone. That is a reason I am concerned with the Exception. Will appreciate any attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated your problem and have found a way to fix it that may work for you. I believe the error is occurring because of the size of your Canvas being set to zero when you try to resize it in Overlay mode.

**Firstly:** You need to set your Canvas *Render Mode* to World Space, or else resizing the Canvas will not be possible (and will result in the error you received) as it will overlay the screen at a set size.

**Secondly:** To return to a view in which resizing the Canvas is possible you need to switch from Sprite mode to Position mode. Then move the Canvas a bit with one of the three axis. This is the way I was able to return to editing the Canvas' size. (I do not know why this works.)

[image: Steps 1 and 2]